# appengine python validator make use of self

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an object that can contain references to other objects of the same type. In my validator I want to ensure the references are not to itself. Is this possible to do?

```
class MyObject(db.Model):

  def not_self_validator(value):
    if self._my_entity == value: #something like this..
      logging.warn('attempted to set object to itself')
      raise ValueError('Unable to set an object to itself')

  _my_entity = db.ReferenceProperty(db._SELF_REFERENCE,required=False,default=None,validator=not_self_validator)
```

Comment: `self` isn't a magic value in Python. If you function is an instance method, it must take `self` as the first parameter. If it's not an instance method, there's no concept of `self` at all you could attach to it.

Comment: Thanks Wooble, that's kind of what I'm asking. In the context of the appengine framework, is it possible to get a reference to self from the validator. I've edited the question to reflect that more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property validator can receive any method/function, but it is not possible to bond that method to self. However you can adapt your validation routine to something like this:

```
def not_self_validator(value):
  #is checks for same address(pointer) whereas == will call the equality method
  if value._my_entity is value:
    logging.warn('attempted to set object to itself')
    raise ValueError('Unable to set an object to itself')
```